# Get count of UIView instances shown on the UI

Tags: uiview, swift4, swift-extensions

Is there a way to count the number of UIView instances created on UI without changing too much code? I need to improve performance, I feel some of the UIView instances are untracked.

Is there a way to create an extension of UIView and always return the number of *live* UIViews?

Thanks!

Comment: Each `UIView` has a property called `subviews`. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Profiler tool to track the allocated UIView objects and check memory leaks.

Also if you like to visually check where your UIViews are located you can use 
"Debug View Hierarchy" tool.

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]